# Wrong return_value in Pytest Mock

Tags: python, pytest

```
import pytest

from flightrecommendation.flight_score import CalculateScore
# from unittest.mock import MagicMock,patch
import unittest
from unittest import mock

from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch,Mock

from pytest_mock import mocker


class TestGetUserRewardPoints(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(MysqlConnector, 'connect_db')
    def test_get_user_reward_points(self, mock_connect_db):
        # Set up the mock MysqlConnector
        mock_cursor = MagicMock()
        mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = [{'employee_points': 30}]
        mock_connect_db.return_value.__enter__.return_value.cursor.return_value = mock_cursor

        # Call the function under test
        result = get_user_reward_points("6")

        # Check the result
        self.assertEqual(result, {'reward_points': 30})

        # Check that MysqlConnector.connect_db was called once
        mock_connect_db.assert_called_once_with('app')

        # Check that the SQL query was constructed and executed correctly
        expected_query = "select * from client where id='6'"
        mock_cursor.execute.assert_called_once_with(expected_query)

        # Check that fetchall was called once
        mock_cursor.fetchall.assert_called_once()

        # Check that the fetchall result was properly parsed
        mock_cursor.fetchall.return_value = [{'employee_points': 'invalid'}]
        result = get_user_reward_points("6")
        self.assertEqual(result, {'reward_points': 0})
```

Writing test case for my function

```
def get_user_reward_points(client_id):
    try:
        conn = MysqlConnector.connect_db("app")
        query = """select * from client where id='%s' """ % client_id
        reward_points = 0
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if result:
                reward_points = result[0]['employee_points']
            print("kkkk")
            print(result)
        return {'reward_points': reward_points}
```

Written test function for get_user_reward_points function. Getting result value as  } .Expecting return_value which i have set as
{'reward_points': 30}

Getting  {'reward_points': }
Expecting {'reward_points': 30}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.